# Searching through list of tuples

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function that accepts a string and a list of tuple pairs. I want to search through the list of tuples, and if the first value in the tuple matches the input string, I want to return the second value in the pair. I believe it functions similar to the [`lookup`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-List.html#v:lookup) function, but I'm not sure how to implement it. Here is my thinking so far:

```
search :: a -> [(a,b)] -> Maybe b
search a (x:xs) = if a == first value in x, return second value in x
-- If a is not in the list of tuples, return "Nothing"
```

An example of this would be:

```
search "x" ([("x", 3), ("z", 5)]) = 3
search "x" ([("y", 3), ("z", 5)]) = Nothing
```

Comment: What is `S`? And how is this not _exactly_ the same as `lookup`?

Comment: I deleted that S, apologies, it was from an incorrectly attempted code. Because lookup returns "Just x" rather than "x".

Comment: Yes, but if the return type is `Maybe b` then you _can_ only return `Just x`. By itself, `x` has the wrong type (`b`, not `Maybe b`).

Comment: Ah okay I understand! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In the base case, if list is empty, it returns `Nothing`. Then, if first element `a` of tuple in the head is equal to element `x`, it returns second element `Just b`. Else, recursively, it searchs in the tail.

```
search :: (Eq a) => a -> [(a,b)] -> Maybe b
search _ [] = Nothing
search x ((a,b):xs) = if x == a then Just b else search x xs
```

You can implement an unsafe version without `Maybe`:

```
search :: (Eq a) => a -> [(a,b)] -> b
search _ [] = error "element not found"
search x ((a,b):xs) = if x == a then b else search x xs
```

Other option is searching a list instead of first ocurrence, then, empty list `[]` is equivalent to `Nothing`:

```
search :: (Eq a) => a -> [(a,b)] -> [b]
search x = map snd . filter ((==x).fst)
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted help understanding why her code wasn't working, not the solution. If it was the latter, she could've looked up the definition of `lookup` herself.

Comment: No I do want to know how to make this code work. I want to write this function called "search", not just use the lookup function. I just know that it functions similar to the lookup function

Comment: Haskell has some basic unsafe functions (like `head`). If the OP want to remove `Just` context, that is the simplest way to do it.

Comment: "Haskell has some basic unsafe functions" -- That doesn't make it a good idea to create even more of them. In particular, `head` and `tail`  should be flat-out avoided, specially by beginners -- using them is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: It depends on the use context of the function. Perhaps the OP is certain that the key is in the list. Otherwise, of course, a safe version is better.

Comment: "Perhaps the OP is certain that the key is in the list" -- In such cases (i.e. if the absence of the key is a bug) it is better to either throw the error at usage point (`fromMaybe (error "x key missing from degarbling list -- this is a bug")`) or to use [`lookupJustNote`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.8/safe-0.3.9/Safe.html#v:lookupJustNote) from *safe*. That way at least you get an informative error message.

Answer (score 3):

[`find`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:find) can retrieve the first element satisfying an arbitrary condition, and so you might build your function around it:

```
-- 'fmap snd' acts on the 'Maybe (a, b)' that 'find' gives back.
search :: Eq a => a -> [(a,b)] -> Maybe b
search a = fmap snd . find ((== a) . fst)
```

Note that this is exactly the same as `lookup`. Also, as leftaroundabout points out, `3` (as opposed to `Just 3`) is not a possible result for a function with a `Maybe b` result type. You can eliminate the `Maybe` wrapping when you actually need to use the result using, for instance, the `maybe` function:

```
GHCi> :t maybe
maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
GHCi> (maybe "No x" (("x ~> " ++) . show) . search "x") ([("x", 3), ("z", 5)])
"x ~> 3"
GHCi> (maybe "No x" (("x ~> " ++) . show) . search "x") ([("y", 3), ("z", 5)])
"No x"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple map combined with a lambda:

```
searchMe :: (Eq a) => a -> [(a, b)] -> [Maybe b]
searchMe a li = map (\(x, y) -> if a == x then Just y else Nothing ) li
```

OP your function, as it is, won't work as you are defining your list parameter as (x : xs), which won't enable you to apply operations to elements of the tuple.

Comment: (1) `(Eq a) => a -> [(a, b)] -> [Maybe b]` will work fine -- in your implementation, only `x` needs to have the same type of `a`. (2) This gives a list of `Maybe a`, while the OP only wants the first `Just`-value in the list. You need something like `listToMaybe . catMaybes` (both are in `Data.Maybe`) to perform this final step.